# Django, how to make a download button for a script displayed on the website

Tags: javascript, python, django, download

In my Django project, I display a Python script, and I'd like to make a `Download` button above it which they can click and have their browser download the script. How can I achieve this?

Using Django 1.8.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already documented in docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment

```
response = HttpResponse(my_data, content_type='text/x-python')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="foo.py"'
```